# How can I change the date format in datePicker?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I change the date format in datePicker (Material ui)?

Now I have this date format - **MM/dd/yyyy**

How to display in this format - **dd/MM/yyyy**?

```
   <KeyboardDatePicker
     margin="normal"
     id="date-picker-dialog"
     format="MM/dd/yyyy"
     value={dateFrom}
     KeyboardButtonProps={{
      'aria-label': 'change date',
     }}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, if you mean a format like day/month/year, you have just to change `format` prop into `DD/MM/YYYY`.

If you mean a format like dayOfWeek/month/year, you have just to change `format` prop into `dd/MM/YYYY`.

In any cases, year must be always in capitol letters (YYYY).

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-date-picker-forked-z801u?file=/demo.js) a codesandbox example with all the above options.

Comment: @luckydev https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/issues/1442 its a library bug. As expleined on docs, you have to use "@date-io/moment": "^1.3.13" and everything works fine